# What is the expected time to roll all $1$ through $6$ on a six-sided die?

Tags: probability, expected-value, dice

> What is the expected time to roll all $1$ through $6$ on a six-sided die?

Recently I came across the above question. When I tried to solve the above question, I thought of $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$. Implementing the above method to solve this question, I got the answer as $36$, which is definitely wrong. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? My solution is:

$$E(\text{all six}) = E(1) + E(2) + \ldots + E(6) = 6 + 6 + \ldots + 6 = 36$$

Comment: This is the coupon collector's problem.

Comment: Google "coupon collector problem". The correct answer is $(1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6)\cdot 6=14.7$ What you miss that you do not need $6$ throws to get the first, second third distinct result. For the first , you only need $1$ throw, for the second in average $6/5$ throws and so on.

Comment: Your answer would be correct if you specified the order.  That is, if you tossed until you got the first $1$, then tossed until you got the next $2$, and so on.  Very different problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that those six events are not independent.  If you needed to a roll a 1 through 6 in that order, your answer would be appropriate.  But whatever you roll on the first throw is a number you don't need to throw again, so the analysis is going to be different.